# Oracle database -- how can I combine these two tables so that the where clause looks at multiple values?

Tags: sql, oracle

Really not sure how to word this. I have two tables, t1 and t2. t1 contains a very long history of messages, so it has [message, t1_id, t2_d]. t2, for the sake of the example just has t2_id. I want to find the message correlated with the highest t1_id. That's easy

```
select message
from t1
where t1_id = (
    select MAX(t1_id) as mx
    from t1
    where t2_id = 1
);
```

But as you can see, I have hard coded the t2_id. My intention is for this code (which currently just returns the highest message from the one id) to do so an ALL distinct id's. There's a few ways to do this, but I know you can do

```
select t2_id
from t2;
```

So how can I essentially replace the hard coding with the above select statement? I know I can't directly, but even using GROUP BY I was having no luck.

---

Clarification: the t2_id column in t1 correlates to the t2_id column in t2. So in t1 there will be many repeats of t2_id's from t2. So I just want the message for EACH t2_id in t1 that has the highest t1_id. So t1 has thousands of rows but only about 20 different t2_id's, so I should have 20 row result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient solution (probably the most efficient one), using slightly more advanced features.

```
select t2_id,                     -- you probably need this! 
       max(t1_id) as max_t1_id,   -- if needed
       max(message) keep (dense_rank last order by t1_id) as message
from t1
group by t2_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select message
from t1
where t1_id = (
    select MAX(t1_id) as mx
    from t1 ttt
    where t1.t2_id = ttt.t2_id
);
```

There are other ways to express this query -- using `row_number()`, `keep`, `join` are typical ways.  But keeping with your form, a correlated subquery is one way to go.

Comment: my apologies if I seem confused. Wouldn't this also return just one message (the one with the highest t1_id) rather than the highest message for each t1_id?

Comment: @skex - no, this will return one result per each distinct `t2_id`. It is quite inefficient though - for example, it will compute the same `max(t1_id)` several times for the same `t2_id`. This solution is closest to what you were doing in your solution - that's Gordon's point, he provided the solution that most resembles what you had already done.